# Rails 3: How to add a module to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, module, include

I've got a User model in my Rails 3 app which is getting huge. I want to extract a bunch of functions which are related to subscription billing and place them in a module.

This is the first time I've attempted to write a module, and the first thing I tried was just to create a minimal module with a test method and see if it worked.

I created the `/lib/modules` directory and added it to my autoload paths. Then I created the file `recurly_extensions.rb` in that directory. The file looks like this:

```
Module RecurlyExtensions

    def foobar
        "This works."
    end

end
```

Then I added this to my user model:

```
include RecurlyExtensions
```

Then I tried to load the rails console to test if I could call `.foobar` on a User instance. However, the console won't load.

I get this error message:

```
/Users/Andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `load': /Users/Andrew/Rails/fourth_env/lib/modules/recurly_extensions.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (SyntaxError)
```

So, it's saying I'm missing an `end` somewhere, but I don't see it.

Can anyone help me understand how to properly set up a module to be included in a Rails model? Thanks!

Comment: what is `Module`? it should be `module`

Comment: Oh for crying out loud, that's all that was wrong. Sheesh! Hey why don't you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I often face this kind of stupid errors :)

Comment: @nash - I could, but I'd rather give credit where credit is due...

Comment: @apneadiving I'm glad I'm not the only one that deals with stupid errors.. Answers to these seemingly simple questions is what I spend most of my debugging looking for cause its always something simple that gets overlooked. *kuddos*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should replace `Module` with `module`